# how to make reversed scope in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

in my index action, i have

```
@messages = Message.scoped.page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

I want those messages to be ordered by id as they are now, but reversed. How to accomplish that in controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
@messages = Message.order('id DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

Comment: @KubaPolaczek it's unnecessary.